# npm install why is everything being executed?

Tags: angular, npm

First off, I'm really new to this npm stuff as well as Angular. I'm on a project which I had been lead to believe worked on our sandbox area. Main development in the past was done on an area that had access to the internet to pull packages but the current environment that I am in is not able to connect to the network. We have a repository on the internal network that we are pulling packages from.

There are a multitude of issue I'm running into but I'm just trying to get past 1 at a time.
I thought I could just run an npm install packageName in order to see if I can pull the latest version of just a single package. It would appear that the projects `package.json` is always getting executed despite my attempts to only pull the specified project. I know it is reading the `package.json` file because I have already traced the error to a package that does not exist called popper. If I remove the popper from the `package.json` file then that error is gone.
How may I only pull a package and nothing else?
e.g. Trying to only pull the latest package for angular5-csv.

```
npm install angular5-csv
npm install angular5-csv --no-optional
npm install angular5-csv --production --no-package-lock --no-save
npm install angular5-csv --production --no-package-lock --no-save
```

Am I wrong in thinking that the `package.json` should not be read all the time?
I know it is executed because 100+ packages get updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you install a package, along with that dependancies of package also get downloaded. If you read this npm [docs on npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm#dependencies). It says
`If a package references to another package with a git URL, npm depends on a preinstalled git.` So it will use system installed git to get those dependencies or update the current packages as per the dependencies of the installing package. This will cause to `update your packages as underlying dependencies is also getting updated`.

If you compare now this with yarn, `yarn add` causes `it places the package on disk. During the next install, this package will be used instead of sending an HTTP request to get the tarball from the registry.`
The desire action you were looking for.

One way to avoid that is that using semantic versioning as intended and specify `"angular5-csv": "1.0.0"` in your package.json for your apps. This way package-lock.json will get definite version of package and npm will not update those packages.

Answer (score 0):

One simple workaround might be renaming your package.json + install + rename again:

```
mv package.json package.bak
npm install <package_name> --no-save
mv package.bak package.json
```

Depending on the content of your package.json you can try

- `npm install`: will install both "dependencies" and "devDependencies"
- `npm install --production`: will only install "dependencies"
- `npm install --dev`: will only install "devDependencies"

Comment: I'm attempting this but I still get the ERR! for the reference to missing package that I know goes away when I remove the entry that is in the package.json file. Being that the package is not found it attempts to reach out to github.com... Should I delete the node_modules entirely?

Comment: Cleaning up node_modules is always a good idea. After this you NEED to run npm install. Btw. why you wanna install single packages? Normally you only do this if you add new packages. The default would be: clone the sources, run 'npm install', run 'npm start'